# Video-JS buttons not showing when run from IIS 6

Tags: html, html5-video, video.js

When I run my project from Visual Studio 2012 the Video-JS works great. When I deploy to the server using IIS 6 the videos play but no buttons! I have added every mime type needed.

Comment: Have you checked the headers of files when they're sent to make sure the right mime types are coming through?

Comment: When run from Visual Studio the headers are: Accept: application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, */*   When I run from the server: Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*